# can't find the android keystore directory on linux for rhomobile android app

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

i built rhomobile android app for production which generated a keystore.
where can i find this keystore?
**I am using a linux system.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we build the android app for production it creates a hidden folder under the **home directory**.

Well i found the keystore inside the **.rhomobile** folder.